# How do I select a specific colored cell in datagridview?

Tags: c#, select, datagridview, colors

I want to select some specific columns programatically from my datagridview. Then I will delete them with that codes:

```
        n = 0;
        foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in Olcu_Listesi.SelectedCells)
        {
            if (cell.ColumnIndex == 1 || cell.ColumnIndex == 2)
            {
                Olcu_Listesi[1, cell.RowIndex].Value = null;
                Olcu_Listesi[2, cell.RowIndex].Value = null;
                Olcu_Listesi[3, cell.RowIndex].Value = null;

                // Set back color to the first cell inside selected row
                Olcu_Listesi[0, cell.RowIndex].Style.BackColor = DefaultBackColor;
            }

        }
```

This is how colored rows.

So I tried replacing `Olcu_Listesi.SelectedCells` with `Olcu_Listesi[0,x].Style.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;` but it didn't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I suggest you to receive better help write the exact code of how you tried to select cells by background color. The code you've already provided which shows how to change background color makes others confused so it may be hard for them to understands what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, of the `SelectedCells` of your `DataGridView`, you only want to delete those whose `Style.BackColor` property is set to `Color.LightGreen`, correct?

If so, try this:

```
foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in Olcu_Listesi.SelectedCells)
{
    if (Olcu_Listesi[0, cell.RowIndex].Style.BackColor == Color.LightGreen)
        if (cell.ColumnIndex == 1 || cell.ColumnIndex == 2)
        {
            Olcu_Listesi[1, cell.RowIndex].Value = null;
            Olcu_Listesi[2, cell.RowIndex].Value = null;
            Olcu_Listesi[3, cell.RowIndex].Value = null;

            // Set back color to the first cell inside selected row
            Olcu_Listesi[0, cell.RowIndex].Style.BackColor = DefaultBackColor;
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! Actually it wasn't what I ask but your method worked for me. I just added to code  Olcu_Listesi.SelectAll(); and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using below code to select a cell programatically.

```
Olcu_Listesi[0,x].Style.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
```

Please use

```
Olcu_Listesi[0,x].Selected = true;
```